# DropBox in-app login

Tags: objective-c, ios, api, dropbox, in-app

I got DropBox SDK and it linked "correctly".

When I tap my "Link to Dropbox" button, Safari opens, and then I can login and upload/download.

Then I turn off my app completely, restart it, and retry to login to Dropbox. Now, Safari doesn't appear. Of course, it's running in background mode, so I can double-tap the Home button of my iPhone and restart Safari, but I think it's inconvenient and confusing for users.

I found that some apps have in-app Dropbox login functions.
I heard that this is possible in the older DropBox SDK version.
Is this correct?

Can I login to Dropbox in my own app without using Safari?
Is it possible to login with the current Dropbox SDK version?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question, can you please describe it better or provide some code?

Comment: check my answer on
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173815/integrate-dropbox-in-ios-app-but-without-login-pop/23900622#23900622

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, if Safari does it, your app can do it to. It's true that the old SDK used to allow you to do in-app linking. I think it's gone now. I'm not sure if their REST service still allows it. I suspect it does, or else legacy apps would be broken.

The linking that uses Safari simply hits their server at a given URL, so in theory, all you'd have to do is download the content of that URL, which contains a security token to POST back to them along with the user's credentials.

Comment: In that case, how could you get the Multitasking Service to switch to Safari (instead of the user being confused and forced to switch him/herself)?

Answer (score 0):

Current Dropbox SDK allow you to login from your application (if Dropbox app is not installed) or you will redirect to Dropbox app to login