# Integrate Dropbox in ios app, but without login pop

Tags: ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to integrate Dropbox in my app. I have made one sample example using Dropbox document and sample code.

But the issue is, I don't want to open login popup. So is there any way so that I can use dropbox without login or some where I can set default login ID Password and automatically do login. so that I can use dropbox directly.

Thanks,

Hardik Shah

Comment: do you want to access the user's Dropbox or use files from your own?

Comment: Thanks Dan for your response. No we won't use users account. We are ready to use only one account on all devices

Comment: @HardikShah, are you using DropBox as a shared location for your application?

Comment: I could help better if you define would you like just to download files or you would need to upload them as well to dropbox account? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well you could put the files in Dropbox and then share them and use the shared URLs as resources to call. We actually do this for some of our developer [blog assets](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog). Hope that helps. Careful not to move the files otherwise the links will break.

Answer (score 0):

I used DropBox Core API and generated access token.
That worked fine with me.

```
NSString *surl = @"https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/";

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:surl];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

[req setValue:[self getAuth] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
[config setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{@"Authorization": @"Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}];  // replace xs with you access token

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
```

of course you need to handle NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol

that example gives you all files and folders at your dropbox account root

Comment: In [self getAuth], what kind of value should be passed?

Comment: as I commented, access token obtained from dropbox.

Comment: can you show me sample because i add access token but it won't work.